# XAML/WPF Binding to Page.Resources - How does binding flow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am attempting to use 2 DataTemplates to create something like this below:

[image: Horizontally wrapping chips/recipient names]

I need a control that will allow for my dynamically built name-tags (chips per Material Design in XAML) to populate the blue boxed area stacking horizontally first then stacking vertically as each row fills up. Per my understanding a WrapPanel is what I need to use, I've found various examples and have attempted adapting them to fit my needs. I think I'm dang close with this one, but can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Per my understanding My `ScrollViewer.ItemsControl` should bring in my `x:Key="Recipients"` DataTemplate  which should implement my `x:Key="RecipientChip"`DataTemplate for as many instances of `Patient` are in my `IEnumerable<Patient>` set called `Patients`.

I don't think I'm binding things correctly though because when I build, I see nothing printed. It's not throwing any errors in my output tab though so I'm not sure what's going on. My `Patients` IEnumeral is filled like an indexed object as expected. Can someone help me understand why my chips aren't showing up and how the flow of the bindings go? I feel like I'm passing Patients through my ScrollViewer.ItemsControll to the referenced Controls but maybe I'm just reading into this too much?

Here's my code:

XAML

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RecipientChip">
            <StackPanel>
                <materialDesign:Chip
                    Content="{Binding Patient.Name}">
                    <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                        <Image
                            Source="{Binding Patient.Image}" />
                    </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                </materialDesign:Chip>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Recipients">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Recipients:" Background="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                <ItemsControl x:Name="Recipients" ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RecipientChip}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="126*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="66.999"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="193*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <materialDesign:Card
            Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}"
            Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Padding="8"
            Margin="0,65,0,50">
            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Recipients}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public partial class EmailMessageView : Page
    {

        public EmailMessageView(Email email)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Email = email;
            Patients = email.Patients.Data;
            EmailContent.NavigateToString(email.Content);
        }

        public Email Email;
        public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients;
    }
```

Patients

```
-[0]    {Mable} NotificationLinkApp.Models.Patient
        Address "9930 Somewhere St. "   string
        Age 18  double
+       Birthday    {NotificationLinkApp.Models.CarbonDate} NotificationLinkApp.Models.CarbonDate
        City    "Anywhere"  string
        CommunicationId 3   int?
+       CreatedAt   {NotificationLinkApp.Models.CarbonDate} NotificationLinkApp.Models.CarbonDate
        Email   "Mable.Lang@example.com"    string
        FirstName   "Mable" string
        Gender  1   int
        HomePhone   "555-555-4260"  string
        HomePhoneIsLandline null    int?
        Id  1490607 int
        Image   "pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/user-unknown.png"  string
        IsEmail 1   int?
        IsMail  1   int?
        IsPhone 1   int?
        IsReviewRequest 1   int?
        IsText  1   int?
        LanguageId  25493   int?
        LastName    "Lang"  string
        Latitude    "40.527834" string
        Longitude   "-122.318749"   string
        Name    "Mable Lang"    string
        OfficeId    2   int
        ParentId    null    string
        PreferredConfidential   ""  string
        PreferredConfirm    ""  string
        PreferredContact    ""  string
        PreferredRecall ""  string
        ReferenceId "4634"  string
        SSN null    string
        State   "New Mexico"    string
+       UpdatedAt   {NotificationLinkApp.Models.CarbonDate} NotificationLinkApp.Models.CarbonDate
        WirelessPhone   "555-555-4745"  string
        WorkPhone   "555-555-3226"  string
        Zip "90134" string
        _age    0   double
        _email  "Mable.Lang@example.com"    string
        _homePhone  "555-555-4260"  string
        _image  ""  string
        _wirelessPhone  "555-555-4745"  string
        _workPhone  "555-555-3226"  string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to get it to work by simplifying the code some as well as setting the DataContext to Patients. I continued to leverage the native functionality of a WrapPanel so that my "chips" would stack horizontally and wrap to a new line much like text. Here is the working code.

XAML

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RecipientChip">
            <StackPanel>
                <materialDesign:Chip
                    Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                    Content="{Binding Name}" Click="Chip_Clicked">
                    <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                        <Image
                            Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                </materialDesign:Chip>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="126*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="66.999"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="193*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <materialDesign:Card
            Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}"
            Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Padding="8"
            Margin="0,65,0,50">
            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="Recipients:" FontSize="16" />
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RecipientChip}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>

        <WebBrowser Name="EmailContent" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,52,0,10"/>

    </Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
    public EmailMessageView(Email email)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Email = email;
        Patients = email.Patients.Data;
        EmailContent.NavigateToString(email.Content);
        DataContext = Patients;
    }

    public Email Email;
    public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients;
```